# Cannot install GNOME Desktop on Centos 7

Tags: gnome, centos-7

I've very puzzled with my efforts of installing "GNOME Desktop".  When I tried to look at the available group list using command "yum grouplist", I see "GNOME Desktop" is available:

```
Available environment groups:
   Minimal Install
   Compute Node
   Infrastructure Server
   File and Print Server
   MATE Desktop
   Basic Web Server
   Virtualization Host
   Server with GUI
   GNOME Desktop
```

However, when I tried yum group install "GNOME Desktop", I got the following info:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mia.host-engine.com
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: centos.firehosted.com
 * updates: repo.dimenoc.com
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

I'm working on Centos 7.

Could some one kindly suggest what might be wrong?

thanks.

John

Answer (score 1):

The Wiki article has not been updated thoroughly for CentOS. The groups have changed, try

```
yum groupinstall "Desktop"
```

or

```
yum install "Desktop"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you entering a space between 'group' and 'install'?

Try this syntax:

```
# yum groupinstall 'GNOME Desktop'
```

Then:

```
# systemctl set-default graphical.target
# systemctl isolate default.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
su root
yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop"
startx
```

GNOME Desktop Environment will start. When the initial setup runs, you have to configure it for first time.

1. Select system language.
2. Select keyboard type.
3. Add online accounts (optional).
4. Click *Start using CentOS Linux*.